# How to extract text from a variable using Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a business directory using Scrapy and am running into an issue with trying to extract data using variables. Here is the code:

```
    def parse_page(self, response):
    url = response.meta.get('URL')

    # Parse the locations area of the page
    locations = response.css('address::text').extract()
    # Takes the City and Province and removes unicode and removes whitespace,
    # they are still together though.
    city_province = locations[1].replace(u'\xa0', u' ').strip()
    # List of all social links that the business has
    social = response.css('.entry-content > div:nth-child(2) a::attr(href)').extract()

    add_info = response.css('ul.list-border li').extract()
    year = ""

    for info in add_info:
        if 'Year' in info:
            year = info
        else:
            pass

    yield {
        'title': response.css('h1.entry-title::text').extract_first().strip(),
        'description': response.css('p.mb-double::text').extract_first(),
        'phone_number': response.css('div.mb-double ul li::text').extract_first(default="").strip(),
        'email': response.css('div.mb-double ul li a::text').extract_first(default=""),
        'address': locations[0].strip(),
        'city': city_province.split(' ', 1)[0].replace(',', ''),
        'province': city_province.split(' ', 1)[1].replace(',', '').strip(),
        'zip_code': locations[2].strip(),
        'website': response.css('.entry-content > div:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)::attr(href)').extract_first(default=''),
        'facebook': response.css('.entry-content > div:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)::attr(href)').extract_first(default=''),
        'twitter': response.css('.entry-content > div:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)::attr(href)').extract_first(default=''),
        'linkedin': response.css('.entry-content > div:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)::attr(href)').extract_first(default=''),
        'year': year,
        'employees': response.css('.list-border > li:nth-child(2)::text').extract_first(default="").strip(),
        'key_contact': response.css('.list-border > li:nth-child(3)::text').extract_first(default="").strip(),
        'naics': response.css('.list-border > li:nth-child(4)::text').extract_first(default="").strip(),
        'tags': response.css('ul.biz-tags li a::text').extract(),
    }
```

The problem I am having is from here:

```
        add_info = response.css('ul.list-border li').extract()
        year = ""

        for info in add_info:
            if 'Year' in info:
                year = info
            else:
                pass
```

The code checks to see if the information is "Year Established". However, it returns HTML. I am trying to get it so that it just prints out the Year. 
`add_info = response.css('ul.list-border li::text').extract()` will print out the year but how can I do this in the `for` loop?

Whenever "Year" is in `info` it outputs like this: `<li><span>Year Established:</span> 1998</li>`. I am looking to just get the year and not the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following function.

```
def getYear(yearnum):
    yearnum1 = str(yearnum[35:])
    yearnum2 = str(yearnum1[:4])
    return yearnum2
```

Then replace your for statement with the following.

```
for info in add_info:
    if 'Year' in info:
        yearanswer = getYear(info)
    else:
        pass
```

Then it will take the 4 digit number out of your long string and put it in the string yearanswer.
If you print yearanswer is should print 1998. It did for me!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I am looking to extract text from a Python variable that is already defined, rather than a variable in Javascript. I updated the answer to show the result I am getting at the moment.

Comment: How about `for year in yield`?

Comment: I'm sorry @Brendan, I am unsure to what you mean.

Comment: Oh it could be that in `if "Year" in info` has a capital Y. What is you use a lowercase y?

Comment: Try replacing `if 'Year' in info:` with `if 'year' in info:`

Comment: Perhaps I didn't word my question properly, I have my desired result just it's all in HTML still. I am looking to just get the text in it. Look at my updated question to see what result I get. I am just looking for the year.

Comment: Ok. I know what to do. Give me a minute so I can get the correct code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I solved my issue by using BeautifulSoup and grabbing text using it. However, I did use the same method of grabbing the last 4 letters of text. Thanks for the help Brendan!

Comment: Great. Have fun with programming!